# Can not find console app project in Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm a newbie in GCP. Actually, I have 2 projects on this list, but just one is visible. How can I find the second?
I am sure to choose the right organization. And the second project is not deleted because my web has been running without any error.
Thank you all.

[This is my project list in GCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyfLo.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting "No organization" in the dropdown alongside "Select from".

It's confusing but, you can have projects that aren't associated with an organization. It's probable that your other project is thus.

If the project is not listed under "No organization", then another probability is that you used a different Google account (possibly also associated with another organization) to create it.

Note: Because projects are always associated with IAM policies that determine which accounts can access them, it's possible for different projects to be listed under "No organization" for different (Google) accounts.

Comment: I've tried the "No organization" option but I still didn't find it. 
Actually, it is impossible bcoz I have just 2 projects in ONE organization. Even I still could find both of them a few days before, but now it disapeared. :((